# How to properly reimport data and keep the settings in Algolia

Tags: algolia

Case 1: After set a temp index without settings, then copy to the main index i lost the settings in the main index. I have to set the settings again in other process.

Case 2: After set a temp index with settings, and in the settings are specified the index slaves, then copy to the main index, the main index lost the slaves, the index slaves are then belong to the temp index which does not exist because was delete in the algolia copy process.

The docs say:
‘In some cases, you may want to totally change the way your index is structured and need to reindex all your data. In order to keep your existing service running while re-importing your data, we recommend the usage of a temporary index plus an atomical move.’
https://www.algolia.com/doc/node#atomical-re-indexing

The Case 1 work, but there is small moment where the main index don’t have the settings.

Like this statement say: “In order to keep your existing service running while re-importing your data” 
- I have to set a temp index with settings without specified the index slaves, then reimport, then set the full settings again in other process? to avoid that small moment where the main index don’t have the settings.

Comment: You can probably remove the code example, which is not needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when using a temporary index, you need to specify the settings of the main index before doing the move.

The only setting you should not send when doing this is the `slaves` one because the `move_index` operation will not override it.

It wasn't present in the documentation before. It is now modified to contain [a warning](https://www.algolia.com/doc/node#atomical-re-indexing) about this:

> You should set all the settings of the main index on the temporary one, except the `slaves` one. The `move_index` operation will override all the settings of the destination index except this one.